# How do I make my webview in android responsive to jquery and other js library

Tags: android, webview

Hello stackoverflowers,

I created an android webView app for one of my partner website. 
The website is mobile responsive.

Now we decided to develop an app webview android version for the website and we noticed, some slight changes which will affect user experience which are:
1) The nav menu is sticky on the brower and mobile browser but on the android webview, it is not sticky.
2) The popUp tour dialog is not positioning correctly on the webView.

I will attach screenshots

I will appreciate if I can get helps, hints on how to solve it. We tried to create the app on web2app platform and it works just fine.
[web2App demo version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vsqe.jpg)

[Android webView not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OahpU.jpg)

The website link is [tweecampus.com](https://tweecampus.com)

```
    package com.gaspercloud.tweecampus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.Techniques;
import com.daimajia.androidanimations.library.YoYo;

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private float m_downX;
    //    private PullToRefreshView mPullToRefreshView;
    private int REFRESH_DELAY = 3000;
    private ImageView logo;

    private String DEFAULT_ERROR_PAGE_PATH = "file:///android_asset/html/default_error_page.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        context = this;

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.t_icon_white60x60);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");



        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);



        initWebView();
        webView.loadUrl(https://tweecampus.com);
/*
        mPullToRefreshView = findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh);
        mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshView.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mPullToRefreshView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        webView.loadUrl(webView.getUrl());
                        mPullToRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, REFRESH_DELAY);
            }
        });*/
    }


    private void initWebView() {
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(context));
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                view.stopLoading();
                try {
                    view.clearView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                view.loadUrl("about:blank");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                webView.loadUrl(DEFAULT_ERROR_PAGE_PATH);
                webView.clearHistory();
            }
        });
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();

        webView.requestFocus();
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        //webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //this is to reload webPage via JavaScript
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new SimpleWebJavascriptInterface(this, webView), "Android");

        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    //Multi touch detected
                    return true;
                }

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        // save the x
                        m_downX = event.getX();
                    }
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        // set x so that it doesn't move
                        event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
                    }
                    break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.browsermenu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if (!webView.canGoBack()) {
            menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
            menu.getItem(0).getIcon().setAlpha(130);
        } else {
            menu.getItem(0).setEnabled(true);
            menu.getItem(0).getIcon().setAlpha(255);
        }

        if (!webView.canGoForward()) {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
            menu.getItem(1).getIcon().setAlpha(130);
        } else {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
            menu.getItem(1).getIcon().setAlpha(255);
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_back) {
            back();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_forward) {
            forward();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void back() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    }

    private void forward() {
        if (webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.goForward();
        }
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        Context context;

        public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else if (webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.reload();
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.tweecampuswebsite));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried 'webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);' ?

Comment: @Fustigador, yes I have it is inside the initWebView() method, even the nav menu hamburger is not showing the nav menus and the menu is sticky on browser but on the android webview it is not sticky... you can download and test app debug version here https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqamrc3jhn1igf4/tweecampus.apk?dl=0     

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to inject the javascript when `onPageFinished` invoked? [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39039301/3763032)